# In matlab how can I compute the integral L2 norm in multiple variables?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, integral, absolute-value

I have a function X_t which I have defined anonymously to take as variables t which is a scalar time and z which is a vector of potentially arbitrary dimension.

That is,

```
X_t = @(t,z) fun(t,z).
```

I want to find the integral `L2` norm of this object over the space of z's. That is, I want to find

```
X_t_norm = @(t) integral(@(z) abs(X_t(t,z))^2, -infinity,infinity).
```

Now clearly two things are a problem here.

Firstly, taking the limits as infinite isn't going to work, but I think I should be fine to take the limits as just large numbers (100 would certainly be enough for my purposes).

However, the real problem comes with taking this integral. My variable `z` is a vector of somewhat arbitrary (even) dimension and as a result I've gotten stuck figuring out how to pass `z` into the integral in such a way that I can compute this n-dimensional integral. (Basically I want to vary the length of `z` for different cases and compute the `L2` norm for each of these cases).

In particular, I'm not sure how to tell the integral function to compute the integral over every component of z between the limits discussed above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Those aren't integral norms. I need the capital L2 norm not the lowercase l2 norm.

Comment: When you say "dimension", I assume here you mean "size", i.e. it could have 10 elements or 100 elements, but `z` will always be a 1D or 2D array?

Comment: Yes it will always be a column vector.

Comment: Not sur to understand but are you looking for `integral(@(t) abs(X_t(t,5)).^2, -inf,inf)` ? where you fix `z` to be whatever you want (in this example z = 5)

Comment: No thats not it at all, z is a **vector** of some dimension and i want integrate with respect to z not with respect to t.

Comment: Your question is not clear, you should edit your question and give us a working example and the expected result. It looks like you want to mix a numerical solution (the function `integral`) with an analytical solution (the function `int`)...  You said that `z` should be a vector, but in your code Z∈ℝ,...

Comment: Frankly I think you just didn't read it or didn't understand it. I made it clear right at the start that z was a vector, and it is clear that the integral is respect to z given a specific value of t. The fact that I didnt write z out explicitly as a vector is rather the whole point of the question since it is of arbitrary dimension. Nowhere in my code do i specify that z is a real number except maybe in the limits which are really only there to indicate that i want to integrate across all values of z in all components.

Comment: I thought the question was clear. **Is there an upper bound on the size of `z`?** You need to keep in mind that if `z` is very high dimensional then a brute force numerical approximation of the integral is going to be very slow. For example, if `z` is 100-dimensional, and say we only use 10 samples along each dimension to estimate the integral, then we require at least 10^100 samples of the function which is infeasible.